# Cannot install apps after removing memory card

Tags: applications, sd-card, installation, uninstallation, lg-g6

The memory card slot of my phone stopped working and some of my apps were stored in the memory card. Now i am unable to install the app again in the phone memory. [image: this is the error]

So any idea? I tried to follow the steps in the link in the picture, but dosen't help.

Comment: Was the memory card running as adoptable memory? What is your phone model and which Android version are you running? Please enable Developer options and adb and try to nstall and app via `adb install <appname.apk>`. If it does not work you will see a error message that you can post here.

Comment: if you don't care about data on it forgetting SD Card in settings should fix. be aware it is not recoverable all data is lost